# Compiling aflex in linux mint 64 bit

Tags: linux, compilation, 64-bit, ada

I have the following folder containing the source files for AFLEX http://snk.to/f-cd1c0j3u but I can't find out how to compile them so I can use them in my ADA project (I use gnat-gps and Linux Mint 15 64 bits). It doesn't seem to have a project file, only sources.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Ada - no makefile necessary.

Find the toplevel file (*.adb) and gnatmake it. This works because Ada tracks all the dependencies so project files aren't essential (though they are often used for convenience, storing flags, paths etc, and are usually required in mixed language projects).

On Linux you will need to lower-case all the filenames first, or find an "ignore case in filenames" option; I'm guessing this project came from Windows.

Just checked : lowercasing the filenames,

```
gnatmake aflex.adb
```

builds successfully (with some warnings).

Comment: It worked after running a script to change all filenames to lowercase. As you said it did give some warnings,but I suppose it's normal. Thanks.

Comment: It is up to you to analyze the warnings and fix them where appropriate.

Comment: It's part of an assignment so it's supposed to work as it is, at least in windows. I don't think the warnings are specific to linux so I would assume there's nothing to fix.

Comment: Assuming that warnings can be ignored is a bad assumption. Something may be legally compileable, but break during runtime because of the warned-about situation.

Comment: I would normally agree. In this case they all seem to be "variable never read and never assigned" so they won't hurt the questioner's project. But ... not good practice; regarded as a serious error in high reliability code.

Comment: Variale never read or variable never assigned hints at some possible problems in algorithm.